# How to limit the max rows without Using Pageable for JPASpecificationsExecutor?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to understand and figure out the solution for the following use case

These are my entity classes

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User  {
  private UserID id;
  private Set<UserAddress> addresses = new HashSet<UserAddress>(0);
  @EmbeddedId
  @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "userId", column = @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, length = 32)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "userType", column = @Column(name = "USER_TYPE", nullable = false, precision = 12, scale = 0)) })
  public User getId() {
     return this.id;
  }
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  mappedBy = "user", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})    
  @BatchSize(size=50)
  public Set<UserAddress> getAddresses() {
    return this.addresses;
  }
  ........
}
```

UserAddress

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERADDRESS")
public class UserAddress  {
  private UserID id;
  Private User user;
  private String address; 
  @EmbeddedId
  @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "userId", column = @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, length = 32)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "userType", column = @Column(name = "USER_TYPE", nullable = false, precision = 12, scale = 0)) })
  public User getId() {
     return this.id;
  }
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns( {
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "userType", referencedColumnName = "USER_TYPE", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false) })
  public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
  }
  ........
}
```

UserId

```
@Embeddable
public class UserId implements Serializable {
   private String userNo;
   private Long UserType;
   .......
   .......
}
```

I have created a staticmetamodel class for User, UserID and UserAddress and created query based on Specifications.

Metamodel class for User

```
@StaticMetamodel(User.class)
public abstract class User_ {

  public static volatile SetAttribute<User, UserAddress> addresses;
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, UserID> id;
}
```

Metamodel for UserId

```
@StaticMetamodel(UserID.class)
public abstract class UserID_ {
   public static volatile SingularAttribute<UserID, String> userNo;
   public static volatile SingularAttribute<UserID, Long> UserType;
}
```

**I am trying to retrieve maximum of 10 User objects ordered by UserType and searched based on userId. The query has to retrieve the UserAddresses as an eager fetch.**

My Specification Object is

UserSpecification

```
public class UserSpecifications {
   public static Specification<User> userNoIs(String userNo) {
      return (root, query, cb) -> {
        root.fetch(User_.addresses);
        return cb.equal(root.get(User_.id).get(UserID_.userNo),userNo);
      };
   }
}
```

DAO Function:

```
 Sort sortInstructions = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id.userNo");
 Pageable pageInfo = new PageRequest(0, maxCount, sortInstructions);
 Specifications<User> specifications = Specifications.where(userNoIs(input.getUserNo()));
 Page<User> responseList= userRepository.findAll(specifications,pageInfo);
```

I am getting the following exception when I run the above statement.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias1,role=com.entity.User.addresses,tableName=USERADDRESS ,tableAlias=useraddress1_,origin=USER user0,columns={user0.USER_TYPE user0.USER_ID ,className=com.entity.UserAddress}}]
```

But apart from that I also need to understand how to limit the no of rows returned using Specification but without using Pageable . If I use Pageable, then a separate query will be fired to retrieve the count of rows and then actual query is being fired. My application is performance oriented, and I do not want to have any extra queries being fired.

Is there any way where I can limit the no of rows without using Pageable, but using Specifications ?

Comment: You want just fetch first X results?

Comment: Yes. I want to just fetch the first X Results. But when I do call with repository.findall(speciciations,pageInstructions) it performs an extra query to get the count of rows. In this case I can handle pagination in application code layer instead of Db layer.  I am not able to find an API for repository with specifications and page limit without using Pageable interface

Comment: I'm not really convinced that handling pagination in code is faster than handling it in DB layer. All you complicated operation including filtering, pagination should be done in DB side, you can check some performance tests for that

Comment: It makes sense to go Pageable interface, if I want to find out how many pages are available based on the max size and data available on DB. But in  my scenario, all I need to do is just get 10 records greater/lesser than page marker (eg. userid) .  I don't need to find out how many pages are available.  For this, firing an extra query to find count is a costlier operation on a high volume table.

Comment: So you want first X results or X results after Y results?

Comment: Ideally yes. That is the simple scenario. We can use regular CriteriaBuilder and achieve that in our code. But I am trying to use Specifications of JPA to make the code more abstract and re-usable

Comment: I tried with version 1.6.2.RELEASE as you have mentioned. But still facing the same issue. Is there any issue with fetch which I am using. Should I use join instead ? But I tried with Join before and I saw multiple subqueries being fired

Comment: Please edit you question with:
1. Specified question about expected behavior 
2. Code which generate exception - in you sitatution this specification.

Comment: I have edited the question with required details. Hopefully it explains the pageable issue which I am facing

Comment: One more thing - why you need fetch join when you are using `FetchType.EAGER`?

Comment: If I don't use Fetch join, I am seeing two queries being fired. One for getting User entity and another for joining with User and UserAddress entitiy. But if I do the same thing with fetch I am able to see that only one query is being fired which joins between User and UserAddress.